# <img> not 100% width in Bootstrap grid?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

It's technically very simple code of displaying two images next to each other:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb"
crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color: black;" >
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/518x278.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9" style="background-color: yellow;">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1411x278.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

However, the images do not fill the `col` container width 100% (as evident by the still visibile background-color? Why aren't they stretching to fill the container?

I have tried setting `margin` to `0px` and explicitly stating `width: 100%;` as you see, but it doesn't work. I have no other formatting except the Boostrap default min.css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why aren't they stretching to fill the container?

That's because a Bootstrap row normally has gutters in it. (which means each column in a row has 15px left and right padding)

Add the class `no-gutters` to the row to remove the gutters.

And add the `px-0` class to the container to remove the horizontal padding on the container if needed.

Comment: It seems if I add `no-gutters`, the `cols` are edge to edge, but the container does not go all the way to the edge of the screen anymore? Why is that?

Comment: Add the `px-0` class to the container. That removes the horizontal padding.

Comment: I have a similar problem and using no-gutters but most important, using px-0 in the contaner-fluid solved my problem!, thanks Davide

Answer (score 2):

`col-md-3` and `col-md-9` both have 15px padding.

Adding `no-gutters` to the row div will remove the padding.

Comment: is it okay to overwrite the `style` of `col` directly or should this be avoided due to the set Bootstrap grid?

Comment: change your <div class="row"> to <div class="row no-gutters">

Comment: It seems if I add `no-gutters`, the `cols` are edge to edge, but the container does not go all the way to the edge of the screen anymore? Why is that?